# Laravel + Jetstream + Inertia . No funciona el event click del componente default DangerButton

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

tengo un pequeño componente vue, con el cual estoy mirando todos los compoenentes que tra e Jetstream. Y probando uno qye se llama DangerButton.vue he querido hacer un simple on click pero no funciona el evento, mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
               Testeando componentes
            </h2>
        </template>
        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg px-4 py-4">
                    <danger-button @click="saludar">Hola</danger-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>
<script>
    import AppLayout from './../Layouts/AppLayout'
    import Welcome from './../Jetstream/Welcome'
    import DangerButton from './../Jetstream/DangerButton'
    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
            Welcome,
            DangerButton
        },
        props: ['data', 'errors'],
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            saludar(){
                alert('Hola !');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

El boton se muestra correctamente, en rojo y tal, pero no se activa el `@click`. ¿Que puede ser? Repito, el componente viene con **laravel-jetstream**